# QVariant::QVariant(Qt::GlobalColor)' is private

Tags: qt, qt5

declaration in header file

```
QColor dialogBoja, dialogBoja1;
```

.cpp file

```
dialogBoja = postavke.value("boja", Qt::black).toString();
//postavke means settings
dialogBoja1 = postavke.value("boja1", Qt::white).toString();
```

As I said on title, when I try to compile this in Qt5 I get error: QVariant::QVariant(Qt::GlobalColor)' is private

How to solve this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to explicitly create a QColor object.  This should work:

```
dialogBoja = postavke.value("boja", QColor(Qt::black)).toString();
```

The reason for this is explained in the header:

```
// These constructors don't create QVariants of the type associcated
// with the enum, as expected, but they would create a QVariant of
// type int with the value of the enum value.
// Use QVariant v = QColor(Qt::red) instead of QVariant v = Qt::red for
// example.
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like they wanted to divorce QVariant from the QtGui modules, like QColor, and removed that constructor in 5.0. Some syntax is explained [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvariant.html#a-note-on-gui-types).

> Because QVariant is part of the QtCore library, it cannot provide
>   conversion functions to data types defined in QtGui, such as QColor,
>   QImage, and QPixmap. In other words, there is no toColor() function.
>   Instead, you can use the QVariant::value() or the qvariant_cast()
>   template function.